# 2005 Chevrolet 5.3 using a lot of oil

Tags: chevrolet, suburban, oil-consumption

My 2005 Suburban is using about a quart every 500 miles. I don't see any smoke or leaks. It has a 5.3.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Other than these being thirsty beasts for oi? More than likely it's absorbing it through the PCV. The LS engines are pretty notorious for this. My '06 Silvy is pretty much the same. Putting a catch can inline with the PCV vacuum line may prove this out for you.